# Select an element based on two attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element like this

```
<input type='select' class='MultiSelect' id='myId'>
```

Now I want to get value of a selectbox where it must have **MultiSelect** class and Also Must have **myid** id.

How to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Anything which run on all browsers including IE 6/7

Comment: ID's are unique, but the right way is $('#myId.MultiSelect') as selector $.val() for the value. You can combine more than 1 class $('#myId.MultiSelect.OtherClass.LastClass').... and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with jQuery `$('#myid.MultiSelect').val()`

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript only solution, no jQuery :   http://jsfiddle.net/XFCzN/
But see how beautiful it looks with jQuery.

```
<input type='select' class='OtherClass' id='myid' value='no' >
<input type='select' class='MultiSelect' id='myid' value='yes' >
<input type='select' class='MultiSelect' id='nomyid' value='no' >
```

Script :

```
var reqInput = getByTwo("INPUT","MultiSelect","myid");
if(reqInput != null)
  alert(reqInput.value);
else
  alert("No Match");

function getByTwo(tagName,myClass,myId)
{
var myInputs = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
for(var i=0;i< myInputs.length;i++)
{
    if((myInputs[i].getAttribute('class') == myClass) && (myInputs[i].id == myId))
     return myInputs[i];    
}

return null; 
 }
```